# Allow ui-icon background to be used

Tags: css, jquery-ui

We've got a site wide style sheet that's setting the background on a:link to transparent. This is causing a problem displaying the icons from jqueryui. In the example below the trash can icon associated with the ui-icon-trash CSS class is not being displayed because the a:link background property overrules it.

I could apply the same styles ui-icon-trash uses to the link in question but that will be fragile if the jqueryui theme were ever to be updated in the future. Is there a way I can get the jqueryio icons to display at the same time as having a site wide background:transparent property on a:link?

```
<html>
  <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css" />
 <style>
   a:link {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #066E37;
    background: transparent;
    } 
  </style>
   </head>
   <body>
     <a class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" href="#"></a>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a real solution there, but I can offer two hacks:

1. Put an additional `<span>` inside the `<a>` and apply the css to this element.
2. Don't use `<a>` but `<button>` instead. Drawback: this would require additional javascript to make the button work.

If it is sufficient to override only the background color of your links, `background-color: transparent` instead of `background: transparent` could do the trick (but I guess you might have thought of that already).

Comment: Nope I hand't thought of setting the background-color, that worked a treat!